# How do I attach files which are located on my web server to send email?

Tags: php, email, outlook-restapi

I am trying to send email following the docs with attachment on https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#SendMessageOnTheFly with PHP. So far I can send a plain email with no attachments. But how do I do it with attachments?

According to docs this is what the response should look like:

```
POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail
{
  "Message": {
    "Subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "Body": {
      "ContentType": "Text",
      "Content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "ToRecipients": [
      {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Address": "garthf@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
        "Name": "menu.txt",
        "ContentBytes": "bWFjIGFuZCBjaGVlc2UgdG9kYXk="
      }
    ]
  },
  "SaveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

What I have is this:

```
public static function sendMessage($access_token, $user_email, $subject, $Content, $email)
{
    $url = "https://example.com/upload.txt";
    $base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($url));
    $arr= array(
        "Message" =>array(
            'Subject' => $subject,
            "Body"=>array(
                "ContentType"=>"HTML",
                "Content"=>$Content,
            ),
        "ToRecipients"=>array(
            array(
                "EmailAddress"=>array(
                    "Address"=>$email,
                )
            ),
        ),
        "Attachments"=> array(
            array(
                "@odata.type"=> "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
                "Name" => "upload.txt",
                "ContentLocation"=> $url,
                "ContentBytes"=> $base64,
                "ContentType" => "text/plain"
            )
        )
    ));

    $json=json_encode($arr, true);
    $getMessagesUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/me/sendmail";

    return self::makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "POST",$getMessagesUrl,$json);
}
```

and then I call the method outside:

```
var_dump(OutlookService::sendMessage($tokens['access_token'], $_SESSION['user_email'], 'subject', 'body', 'abc@gmail.com'));
```

I am clueless about going with this. This is not working and giving me a 400 error. I am aware of the 400 error but don't know what could be causing it.

What should I be doing here? What's the right format?

Comment: It's always a good idea to try your request at http://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/, it helps to quickly tweak things and see what works. I ran your JSON payload generation code and put the resulting JSON into the sandbox, and it worked fine, so it's likely something in how your transmitting the data or something about your file.

Comment: Note that 400 errors often have a response body that contains error information. That might provide a clue here.

Comment: @JasonJohnston Your second comment was my hint. The 400 error did have information about the error. For some reason I made a mistake in placing `SavetoSentItems` in the Json array in my real code and I assumed it was in the right spot for some reason. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Cool! You should post the details as an answer here to help other folks :)

Comment: @JasonJohnston Yup doing that as I write this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with your example, the first thing that poped in my eyes was that you did not set you attachments as in the example

also the documentation specifies **SavetoSentItems** is required, so that should be added also

Here is the modified version that should print out the json as requested in the sample :

```
public static function sendMessage($access_token, $user_email, $subject, $Content, $email)
{
    $url = "https://example.com/upload.txt";
    $base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($url));
    $arr= array(
        "Message" =>array(
            'Subject' => $subject,
            "Body"=>array(
                "ContentType"=>"HTML",
                "Content"=>$Content,
            ),
        "ToRecipients"=>array(
            array(
                "EmailAddress"=>array(
                    "Address"=>$email,
                )
            ),
        ),
        "Attachments"=> array(
            array(
                "@odata.type"=> "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
                "Name" => "upload.txt",
                "ContentLocation"=> $url,
                "ContentBytes"=> $base64,
                "ContentType" => "text/plain"
            )
        )
    ),
    "SaveToSentItems" => "false"
    );

    $json=json_encode($arr, true);
    $getMessagesUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/me/sendmail";

    return self::makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "POST",$getMessagesUrl,$json);
}
```

edit with only changed lines :

```
    "Attachments"=> array(
        array(
            "@odata.type"=> "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
            "Name" => "upload.txt",
            "ContentLocation"=> $url,
            "ContentBytes"=> $base64,
            "ContentType" => "text/plain"
        )
    )
```

Comment: From the docs: The `SaveToSentItems` parameter is required **only if false.** I don't think you have changed anything else besides that. Even with `SaveToSentItems` it does not work.

Comment: Actually this was it. I made a mistake when I was trying to put SaveToSentItems which screwed up my Jain otherwise the mistake that you pointed out fixed my problem. Thanks.